# How to find MSE for color images?

Tags: matlab, image-processing, signal-processing

I am doing work on color and gray scale images, i find out the Mean Square error for Gray scale but don't know how to find Mean square error  for color images.

I did this for Gray image:

```
 acc = sum( (data_gray(:)- reconstructData(:)).^2 ); 
 mse = acc / numel(data_gray);
```

For color Image the follow code not work, and give me error like: 
**Error using  -
Integers can only be combined with integers of the same class, or scalar doubles.
Error in finalCompress (line 60)
 accRC = sum( (RC(:) - recRC(:)).^2 );**

Code for color image MSE:

```
 accRC = sum( (RC(:) - recRC(:)).^2 ); 
 accGC = sum( (GC(:)- recGC(:)).^2 );
 accBC = sum( (BC(:)- recBC(:)).^2 );
 mse = accRC+accGC+accBC / numel(combineColorChannels);
```

The `combineColorChannels` is the Color image consist of `(recRC,recGC,recBC)`

Comment: The way I uderstand is that MSE is a measure of the image quality. So you need to compare 2 images in order to have a MSE value. If you did for the gray scale there should be no problem applying to color images. Also you should provide the code of what you already did to improve your chances of getting a good answer.

Comment: @brodroll i updated the post :) now you can check please.

Answer (score 1):

The error is pretty clear.  You are trying to implement arithmetic operations between two images that are of different types.  MATLAB is complaining about the differing types.

Because I don't know which of the sets of channels are the differing type, it's best that we cast all of them to `double` before running your code:

```
%// Change
RC = double(RC); 
GC = double(GC);
BC = double(BC);
recRC = double(recRC);
recGC = double(recGC);
recBC = double(recBC);

%// Your code
accRC = sum( (RC(:) - recRC(:)).^2 ); 
accGC = sum( (GC(:)- recGC(:)).^2 );
accBC = sum( (BC(:)- recBC(:)).^2 );
mse = accRC+accGC+accBC / numel(combineColorChannels);
```

If you cast all of the appropriate channels to `double`, the above code should now work.